# Angular: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Trying to perform CRUD operation in Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET Core and Angular. I'm getting the following exception:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This is my service code

```
    getEmployees() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Employee/Index')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
```

And this is my Web API controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Employee/Index")]
public IEnumerable<Employee> Index()
{
     return objemployee.GetAllEmployees();
}
```

And this is my component code:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../services/empservice.service'
@Component({
    selector: 'fetchemployee',
    templateUrl: './fetchemployee.component.html',
    providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class FetchEmployeeComponent {
    public empList: EmployeeData[];

    constructor(public http: Http, private _router: Router, private 
_employeeService: EmployeeService) {
        this.getEmployees();
    }

    getEmployees() {
        this._employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
            data => this.empList = data
        )
    }
}

interface EmployeeData {
     id: number;
     name: string;
     gender: string;
     department: string;
     city: string;
}
```

Comment: That would imply that the data you're getting back from your API is not JSON, but HTML. If you check in the developer tools network tab, can you see your request? What response are you getting?

Comment: Check with your browser’s developer tools whether the request returned successfully. It's likely that the status code is 500 which means that the server application encountered an error. In that case check your server logs to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your return statement with Json() method. Set return type to JsonResult.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Employee/Index")]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    return Json(objemployee.GetAllEmployees());
}
```